# Excel 2010 how to label a row

Tags: worksheet-function

Coumn A in my worksheet has a list of books : Tom Sawyer, Jack and Jill , Phantom, Phantom in four rows. I want to label each row in column B using the logic IF more than one copy of a book is sold it should be labelled "Multi-copy" otherwise Single-copy based on data in column A such that I get a results as shown below

```
  A              B  
1 Title          Label
2 tom Sawyer     Single-copy
3 Jack & Jill    Single- copy
4 Phantom        Multi- copy 
5 Phantom        Multi- copy
```

...any Excel "function" to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try in B2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"Multi-copy","Single-copy")
```

Copy down.